# ClickOnce install with no start menu entry

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

Is it possible to deploy several Windows applications using [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce), but not to have them all create icons on the start menu?

---

The reason for doing this (if you're interested) is that we are distributing several Windows applications within our company. The main one will allow the user to log in and depending on their permissions build a menu of applications they can use. The menu application will fire off the sub applications passing them user anme and password. The menu items will be added dynamically from the database, so other applications can be added as needed. For this reason it cannot be one large ClickOnce install.

It all works apart from the fact that there are a load of items added to the start menu.

Comment: How would you have the user launch the applications?  Just desktop shortcuts, or via a URL?

Comment: Via 1 single menu application

Comment: So then you're planning on launch the application via a URL?  If you're planning on launching the .exe from the menu application then I don't think that's going to work for you.  Click-once applications are not installed like normal applications.  They're typically installed in the user's profile directory and the naming conventions are wierd; specifically you're not going to know what your .exe filename or location is.

Comment: I actually just lauch the install programs each time from the server to run the programs. This just starts the local app on the users harddrive if there are no changes, or does an upgrade if there is a new release. It seems to work exactly the same as clicking the start menu item

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can select, under the "Install Mode and Settings" section, "This application is available online only".  This prevents a start menu item from being created and means that the application can only be launched from the site it's published to.